# Cannot install Timeshift on Kali

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, git

I have been trying to install time shift from the directory I cloned from github.

I ran the following command:

> cd src; make install

And then I seperatly ran:

> sudo make all

Got the following result in both cases:

```
makefile:4: *** No msgmerge found, install it.  Stop.
```

I then tried the command:

> sudo make all

And got the following output:

```
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
makefile:4: *** No msgmerge found, install it.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

After a bit of googling I installed gettext as recommended on online forums:

> sudo apt install gettext

After which I again tried:

> sudo make all

the result:

```
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
makefile:4: *** No valac found, install it.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

After a bit of googling again, I ran:

> sudo apt-get install libvala-dev

After which I gave the command I ran above one more shot:

> ```
> sudo make all
> ```

The result:

```
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
makefile:4: *** No valac found, install it.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

> sudo apt-get install valac

then I ran:

> sudo make all

the result of which is:

```
cd src; make all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
Package vte-2.91 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `vte-2.91.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'vte-2.91' found
/bin/bash: line 0: test: -lt: unary operator expected
Package gtk+-3.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-3.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
/bin/bash: line 0: test: -gt: unary operator expected
#timeshift-gtk
valac -X -D'GETTEXT_PACKAGE="timeshift"' \
        --Xcc="-lm" --Xcc="-O3" -D VTE_291   \
        Core/*.vala Gtk/*.vala Utility/*.vala Utility/Gtk/*.vala \
        -o timeshift-gtk \
        --pkg glib-2.0 --pkg gio-unix-2.0 --pkg posix \
        --pkg gee-0.8 --pkg json-glib-1.0 \
        --pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg vte-2.91 
error: Package `gee-0.8' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
error: Package `vte-2.91' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
make[1]: *** [makefile:52: app-gtk] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/omair/timeshift/src'
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

I am at the verge of giving up here.

**Edit:** I have also tried it after installing libgtk2.0-dev:

> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

Also tried:

Install dependencies

```
sudo apt install -y g++ libgtk-3-dev gtk-doc-tools gnutls-bin \
    valac intltool libpcre2-dev libglib3.0-cil-dev libgnutls28-dev \
    libgirepository1.0-dev libxml2-utils gperf build-essential
```

Get and install vte-ng as per instructions I've found somewhere:

```
git clone https://github.com/thestinger/vte-ng.git
echo export LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/include/gtk-3.0:$LIBRARY_PATH"
cd vte-ng && ./autogen.sh && make && sudo make install
cd ..
```

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift) the timeshift you are talking about? Can you install it using the debfile from [here](https://github.com/teejee2008/Timeshift/releases)?

Comment: Yes that is the timeshift I am talking about.

Comment: Can you install it via the deb making sure you have the dependencies it requires?

Comment: OK. I will try tomorrow. I am curious why the way I tried did not work.

Comment: Kali Linux is a "What you see is what you get" type of distro. It is a stripped down version of Debian with security tools preinstalled. Setting up third-party software [is not supported](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/) despite its highly customizable nature. The things you need for this piece of software might not be included in the Kali repos and thus you would have to start building and maintaining them yourself and deal with all the trouble that would cause for what is ostensibly supposed to be a disposable live boot pen testing distro.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for explaining. I will try installing the .deb file tomorrow and report back to you if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get errors :(

Comment: I ran "apt --fix-broken install" and it still gave me errors, but I finally got timeshift to work. No idea how, since the installer threw shit-ton of errors. Any idea why it works now? I ran sudo dpkg -i [timeshift-file] again after "apt --fix-broken install" . Does that matter?

Comment: One of the said warnings: dpkg: warning: downgrading timeshift from 20.03+ds-2 to 20.03.

Comment: I just found that [timeshift](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/timeshift) is in the repos and is "more up to date" than the one you got likely because it includes modifications for Kali Linux. So you could have just run `apt install timeshift` from the get go. Additionally you got a lot of errors from apt because as a rolling release there can be issues between versions of packages or you missed a few updates, etc. Its not unusual for updates to cause problems on a rolling release.

Comment: I removed the repository that I manually added and ran "apt-get install timeshift". Now if I run "apt-cache policy"  it returns the latest 20.03+ds-2 version of timeshift. However if I check the version by clicking on "about" from the application, I still get "version 20.03". Any ideas? By the way, thanks for your help and the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install [Timeshift](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/timeshift) on Kali Linux you only need to download it from the repositories.

Remove the version you installed yourself by using `apt purge timeshift`.

If you were able to install the package from source, then you can run `timeshift-uninstall` to remove the software. I would also recommend that you clean up the directories containing the source code and binaries to confirm that it is removed from your system.

Confirm that your Kali Linux `/etc/apt/sources.list` only contains the following:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

As pointed out in the [Official Kali Linux documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/), you can run the following to confirm this is the case:

```
grep -v '#' /etc/apt/sources.list | sort -u
```

Additionally you should have nothing present inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

Update your system with `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.

Then install Timeshift with `apt install timeshift`.

Now Timeshift will be installed and managed with your package manager. On a Debian-based system this is the easiest way to keep package and system compatibility high and prevent any package mismatch or [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) type issues.

Kali Linux is a rolling release, so do not be surprised if bleeding-edge upstream packages and libraries introduce system instability or other issues. It is largely designed as a disposable pentesting distro with the most common security tools preinstalled.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but I came across it today when trying to compile Timeshift from source as the error you got is the first error that comes up. I managed to get it compiling, so putting this here for anyone else who may encounter the same issue.

Firstly, thanks a lot for your detailed steps, made my life a whole lot easier!

### First Steps

I performed these steps on Ubuntu 20.04. I followed the steps outlined by Linux Newbie in the question above up to the comment "I am at the verge of giving up here."

#### Installing Dependencies

1. `gee-0.8` and `vte-2.91`

   ```
   error: Package `gee-0.8' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
   error: Package `vte-2.91' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
   ```

   You actually don't need to compile vte, can grab both of them through apt.

   ```
   sudo apt install libgee-0.8-2 libgee-0.8-dev libvte-2.91-dev
   ```

   This unfortunately gets 108MB of packages.
2. `json-glib`

   Most of the make will execute now but it'll fail with the error:

   ```
   error: cc exited with status 256
   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 119 warning(s)
   make[1]: *** [makefile:53: app-gtk] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xxxx/code/timeshift/src'
   make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 2
   ```

   If you look a little further up in the output, you'll notice this error below, need to install one more dependency.

   ```
   timeshift/src/Utility/TeeJee.Json.vala.c:27:10: fatal error: json-glib/json-glib.h: No such file or directory
      27 | #include <json-glib/json-glib.h>
         |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   ```

   Run the command `sudo apt install libjson-glib-dev`

#### Done!

Timeshift will now compile successfully, to install it onto your system run
`sudo make install`

It'll create the relevant files and folders, add it to your path and create the desktop entries. You can run it from the terminal with `sudo timeshift-gtk` or launch it like you would any other app.